# How do I remove "hidden" characters when reading a line of text in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, puppet

I am using a custom Ruby function in Puppet to read a string of text from a file.  I am than comparing whatever version is read against a list of known versions to determine which config file I should use for that particular server.  The problem is that when I compare the read version to my list of known versions, none of them match.

I printed out the variable to the screen, and it looked fine.  I then added a '-' to the beginning and the end and this time, the following was printed

```
-2.2#012-
```

Does anyone know what this is and how it could be removed?

Here is my process.

**A script that handles the installation of an app**

```
sudo echo "2.2" > /opt/version
```

**My ruby function**

```
if FileTest.exists?("/opt/version")
    Facter.add("app_version") do
        setcode do
            version = File.open('/opt/version', &:readline)
            version
        end
     end
end
```

**My puppet manifest**

```
if versioncmp( $app_version, '2.2') == 0 {
            notice("===> Installing 2.2 Configs")
        } elsif versioncmp ($app_version, '2.3') == 0 {
            notice("===> Installing 2.3 Configs")
        } else {
            notice("===> No version match.  Continuing on.")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File.readline` includes the line termination (in your case, "\n").  `chomp` will get rid of the line termination:

```
version = File.open('/opt/version', &:readline).chomp
```

When debugging and you want to see what's *really* in a variable, use `p` instead of `puts`.  `p` will escape unprintable characters so you can see them:

```
puts "2.2\n"    # => 2.2
                #
p "2.2\n"       # => "2.2\n"
```